# How to output a paged_table() within a for loop (using spin() to generate Rmd from R code)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have figured how to have a for loop spit out Rmd using the pander package, e.g.:

```
library(pander)
panderOptions('knitr.auto.asis', FALSE)
##+ results = 'asis'
for (df in dfs) {
    pandoc.header("header text", 1) %>% cat()
    df %>% pandoc.table(align="left") %>% cat()
}
```

but I would like to output a paged_table() using the rmarkdown package. It works just fine outside the loop!

Thanks for your help!